# Jquery + Foreach

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm doing a "keywords/tags" type of form where clients can edit their keywords through a form.

The keywords are sent into the database and are called through the use of **foreach** and **explode**.

So instead of it showing the values like "one,two,three" it is showed as **one** **two** **three**. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFpXs.png)

But when I try to submit the form, this is what it [shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wjT1.png) when I input [these values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ1Lo.png) .

All of the values merges altogether instead of splitting up.

Here's my **ajax** code for the form submit:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#form-basic-update", function(e){
 e.preventDefault();

 var id = $(this).data('target-id');
 var data = $(this).serializeArray();
 $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    url: '/settings/account/public-basic/'+ id,
    success: function(result){

        var text = "You have successfully added your portfolio.";
        var heading = "Success!!";
        successtoast(text,heading);    
        var multikeywords =  $('#keywords').val();
        var arre = multikeywords.replace(/,/g," ");
        $('#public-title').html(`${data[0].value}`);
        $('#public-overview').html(`${data[2].value}`);
        $('#public-service').html(`${data[3].value}`);
       //$('#public-keywords').html(`${data[1].value}`).replace(/,/g,", "); 
        $("span[id='public-keywords']").each(function(){
         $(this).html(arre);   
        });

     }
 });
 });
```

and here's my **PHP** code:

```
<div class="col-4">
  <span class="font-weight-bold">Keywords</span>
</div>
<div id="public-keywords-div" class="col-8 tags-default form-control-settings-account-hide">
  <?php
  $keys = $public_details->keywords;
  $array = explode(',',$keys);
  foreach (($array) as $keywords):
  ?>
<span id="public-keywords"  class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill mx-1 px-3 py-2 mb-1"><?= $keywords; ?></span>                                          
  <?php
  endforeach;
  ?>
 </div>
 <div class="col-8 tags-default form-control-settings-account d-none">
   <input type="text" name="public-keywords" value="<?= $public_details->keywords; ?>" class="form-control-settings-account d-none" id="keywords" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="add tags" />
 </div>
```

Comment: `id` needs to be unique

Comment: Do not use multiple "id" attributes. You better use class for this purpose like `$("span[class='public-keywords']")` and `<span class="public-keywords badge badge-secondary badge-pill mx-1 px-3 py-2 mb-1">`

Comment: is "keywords" not a unique id? i changed it to "keywords-input" and it's still not splitting up

Comment: I mean on php code you are creating multiple spans with same id. If you have 10 elemens on array, you are creating 10 spans with `id="public-keywords"`. Changing id is not making it unique because you are still creating spans by foreach loop. Use class like i mentioned it before.

Comment: Also some users (like me) may can't open imgur urls. Can you please post the error here?

Comment: Found the answer, thank you! You guys are right. I should've used class.

Answer (score 0):

Changed my jquery functions to use **class** instead **id**.

Here's my new ajax code:

`var splitmulti = multikeywords.split(",");`

`$('.public-keywords').remove(); //removes the value inside the span so it won't duplicate`

```
$.each(splitmulti, function(index,field){
  $('#public-keywords-div').append(`<span class="public-keywords badge badge-secondary badge-pill mx-1 px-3 py-2 mb-1">` + field +`</span>`);
}); //splits every input and explodes them into the span class to make them into seperate pills/containers
```